# Cassandra Levelled Compaction - sstables keep growing in size

Tags: cassandra

I have setup Cassandra with Levelled Compaction with sstable_size=256MB. However, my sstables keep growing well beyond 256MB after repeated compactions. I thought they would be capped at 256MB. Am I understanding this correctly?

Here are the table properties:
... ) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.100000 AND caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND comment='' AND dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND gc_grace_seconds=86400 AND index_interval=128 AND read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND replicate_on_write='true' AND populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND default_time_to_live=0 AND speculative_retry='99.0PERCENTILE' AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND compaction={'sstable_size_in_mb': '256', 'class': 'LeveledCompactionStrategy'} AND compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};

Comment: Here are some of the files I see: 1144176565 Dec 3 16:59 objects_2-jb-161-Data.db 374508811 Dec 3 16:59 objects_2-jb-162-Data.db 170982337 Dec 3 16:59 objects_2-jb-179-Data.db 350782428 Nov 25 08:55 objects_2-jb-30-Data.db 3010431098 Nov 25 08:57 objects_2-jb-32-Data.db

Comment: How large is the average partition size?

Comment: Hi Jonathan. How can I find out what the average partition size is? Thanks.

Comment: Compacted partition minimum bytes: 61
Compacted partition maximum bytes: 2874382626
Compacted partition mean bytes: 348835895

Comment: Another thing is that the primary key of the table is defined as (key, version). There are thousands of versions per key. Does this mean that all versions will be stored in the same sstable after compaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have very very large partitions, and the minimum size of an sstable is a single partition.

If you don't need to scan versions-per-partition, you can make each version its own partition by using a composite partition key: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/webhelp/cql/cql_reference/create_table_r.html

If you do need collated versions, then you'll need to consider some kind of "sharding" scheme, e.g. PK ((key, day), version).